# FontAwesome 5 icons not loading in latest chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-awesome-5

I am working in a ASP.NET Core application. I am using Bulma framework and I wish to add FontAwesome icons.

I [went here](https://fontawesome.com/start) and grabbed a CDN link. When I navigate to the page, I don't see any icons.

[image: no icon]

**HTML**

```
<p>Testing: <i class="fab fa-anchor"></i></p>
```

What am I missing? Adding these to my ` section didn't help either.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src *; font-src *; default-src *">
<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src *; font-src *; default-src *">
<meta http-equiv="X-WebKit-CSP" content="style-src *; font-src *; default-src *">
```

Comment: try some other cdn to rule out the issue of cdn. Try this https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: Good suggestion @melvin. I just tried and used `fa fa-bath` which is an icon that is available in 4.7, but I still get the same error. Am I the only one experiencing this issue? I would have thought this would be a very common issue that people faced when developing locally.

Comment: Have you tried alternate cdn ? and still have issue ?

Comment: @melvin yep, I tried the one you told me to try. I got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

try adding use.fontawesome.com to you content security policy.

example:

```
font-src use.fontawesome.com
```

your content security policy rule might have to be changed on the server if its configured there.

if there is already a value for font-src, then separate the value above with a space.

```
font-src example.com use.fontawesome.com
```

Comment: I already have `font-src *`, doesn't that mean accept from all?

Comment: do you have it in the server configuration or as an html like above?
i tried it on my machine and when i have the following ```style-src 'self'``` in my .htaccess file, it wont load third party css files even after i put the meta tags for the content security policy.

Comment: I don't have it in the server configuration. I'm using Kestrel (the one that comes with ASP.NET Core), do I need to set it up in there somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You should try run on web server :D

Or you ca do somthing like that:

1. copy css code for local usage
2. save in to file for ex: awesome.css
3. link file in to your head

i don't know if this is newest one but you can copy that and try:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

```
<i class="fab fa-anchor"></i>
```

Will be inside :D i hope it will help xD